# Resize ToggleButton in JavaFX

Tags: java, css, javafx, resize, radio-button

i have added a Radio Button into an HBox.
The problem is, that i can not resize the Radio Button...

I dont have a caption for the Radio Button, i only need the Button. The Problem is that the Functions setPrefSize/setMaxSize/setMinSize not really change the radius / caliber.

How can i change the Field - Size of the Radio Button and how can i change the radius/caliber?

At the moment, this is my code:

```
//Configuration of the Radio-Button
    radio.setText("");
    radio.setMaxSize(8, 8);
    radio.setPrefSize(8, 8);
    radio.setMinSize(8, 8);
    radio.setStyle("-fx-padding:0;-fx-background-size:0; -fx-border-radius:13px; -fx-background-radius:13px;");
    radio.setSelected(false);
    radio.setVisible(check);
    addComponentToBox(radio);
```

Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve the problem. If you want to style / resize only the dot or the radio you only have to do it like that:

```
    .radio-button .radio {
        -fx-padding: 2px;
     }

     .radio-button .dot {
        -fx-padding: 2px;
     }
```

The padding will set the radius/caliber of the radio/dot!

Comment: Why the heck is that?

Comment: @MichelJung What exactly did you mean?

Comment: Why does one have to use paddings to resize the button rather that width/height as one would expect?

Answer (score 0):

as from stated in [JavaFX CSS Reference Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#radiobutton), you have to style also `dot` (which is a child node of style class `radio-button`. So my suggestion is to create a separate stylesheet (which supports modularisation, reuse and separation of concerns) and in your css do something like

```
.radio-button .radio {
    -fx-border-width: 3px;
    -fx-border-color: red;
    -fx-background-color: white;
    -fx-border-radius: 15px;
    -fx-padding: 10px;
}
.radio-button .radio:selected {
    -fx-background-color: white;
}
.radio-button -radio:armed {
    -fx-background-color: white;
}
.radio-button -radio:determinate {
    -fx-background-color: white;
}
.radio-button -radio:indeterminate {
    -fx-background-color: white;
}
.radio-button .dot {
    -fx-background-radius: 15px;
    -fx-padding: 12px;
}
.radio-button:selected .radio .dot {
    -fx-background-color: red;
}
```

I exaggerated a bit with the styling :-)

Comment: It's not possible to Style the Button with Inline-Styles ? Thanks for your answer...

Comment: As far as I can tell no. Simply because the css pseudoclasses aren't exposed as part of the public API you can use for style manipulation inside Java code.